# SQL Subtract first row from all selected rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to subtract the value of the first selected row from all rows ? So if I have

```
t = 1, v = 500
t = 2, v = 800
t = 3, v = 1200
```

I would get

```
t = 1, v = 0
t = 2, v = 300
t = 3, v = 700
```

I'm always looking for a portable solution but a Postgres solution works just the same :-)
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  v - FIRST_VALUE(v) OVER (ORDER BY t)
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        t
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work

```
SELECT mt2.t, mt2.v - mt1.v AS v
FROM MyTable mt1
CROSS JOIN MyTable mt2
WHERE mt1.t = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Most portable way without using window functions:

```
select v - first
from
  mytable,
  (select v as first from mytable order by t limit 1) as inner
order by t
```

Comment: LIMIT 1 is just as portable as window functions ;)